# 2 levels nested route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

I'm trying to set up 2 levels nested route in rails where dog is a child of owner and meals is a child of dog. Can I do the following ?

```
namespace :admin do
      resources :owners do
           resources :dogs
       end 
       resources :dogs do
           resources :meals
       end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :owners do
    resources :dogs do
      resources :meals
    end
  end
end
```

But to make things less confusing, [Rails has a shallow option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) you can add to nested routes. The reason you might do this is you would want the route to have only the information needed to find the record(s). For instance, to get owner 1's list of dogs, your route would be `owners/1/dogs`, but when you want to show information for dog 5, you only need the dog's id to identify that unique record even if the dog belongs to Owner 1. Without the shallow option, the route for Dog 5 is `owners/1/dogs/5`, but with it, the route is `dogs/5`.

This gets especially useful when you are doing more than one level of nesting. In your situation, if dog 5 had meal 6, then the route for meal 6 would be `owners/1/dogs/5/meals/6`, but with the shallow option, the route for Meal 6 is `meals/6`, while the route for Dog 5's meals is `dogs/5/meals`. You will appreciate using the shallow option when it comes to building the paths.

So with the shallow option, you would do

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :owners do
    resources :dogs, shallow: true do
      resources :meals, shallow: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the SHALLOW option.